# ASP.NET MVC 3 inheriting Membership userId

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I am looking to extend the aspnet_membership in an MVC 3 application by storing extra member details in a separate model/table. I am not looking at using the ASP.NET ProfileProvider.

I would like to use the userId of a member as the primary/foreign key in the additional model/table. How can I achieve this? Is the example code along the right lines?

Thanks for any help.

```
public class Profile
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ProfileId { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public virtual MembershipUser User
    {
        get { return Membership.GetUser(ProfileId); }
    }

    public string FullName
    {
        get { return LastName + ", " + FirstName; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this will not work exactly like you want in EF Code First; you'd need to create an EDMX EF model and include the aspnet tables manually. However, you could also model the aspnet tables and have code first treat them as part of your model... I have never tried that with EF code first and don't know if that's advisable (I suspect it isn't). I've always rolled my own membership (OpenId, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what I do in my project, I have an other class wich is Member and inside I have the Email. I have a AuthenticationService that I use to sing in my user here's the code of this AuthenticationService...

In the web.config I have two differents connection string, one for the application BD and the other for the membership BD.

```
public class AuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
{
    private readonly IConfigHelper _configHelper;
    private readonly ISession _session;

    public AuthenticationService(IConfigHelper configHelper, ISession session)
    {
        _configHelper = configHelper;
        _session = session;
    }

    public bool IsValidLogin(string email, string password)
    {
        CheckLocked(email);
        return Membership.ValidateUser(email, password);
    }

    public void SignIn(string email, bool createPersistentCookie)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(email)) throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty.", "email");
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(email, createPersistentCookie);
    }

    public void SignOut()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    }

    public User GetLoggedUser()
    {
        var email = GetLoggedInUserName();

        if (IsMember())
            return _session.Single<Member>(x => x.Email == email);

        return _session.Single<DelegateMember>(x => x.Email == email);
    }

    public string GetLoggedInUserName()
    {
        return Membership.GetUser() != null ? Membership.GetUser().UserName : string.Empty;
    }

    public MembershipCreateStatus RegisterUser(string email, string password, string role)
    {
        MembershipCreateStatus status;
        //On doit laisser Guid.NewGuid().ToString() sinon ça ne passe pas
        Membership.CreateUser(email, password, email, Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), true, out status);

        if (status == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
        {
            Roles.AddUserToRole(email, role);
        }
        return status;
    }

    public MembershipUserCollection GetAllUsers()
    {
        return Membership.GetAllUsers();
    }

    public string GeneratePassword()
    {
        var alphaCaps = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM";
        var alphaLow = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
        var numerics = "1234567890";
        var special = "@#$";
        var allChars = alphaCaps + alphaLow + numerics + special;
        var r = new Random();
        var generatedPassword = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < MinPasswordLength - 1; i++)
        {
            double rand = r.NextDouble();
            if (i == 0)
            {
                //First character is an upper case alphabet
                generatedPassword += alphaCaps.ToCharArray()[(int)Math.Floor(rand * alphaCaps.Length)];
                //Next one is numeric
                rand = r.NextDouble();
                generatedPassword += numerics.ToCharArray()[(int) Math.Floor(rand*numerics.Length)];
            }
            else
            {
                generatedPassword += allChars.ToCharArray()[(int)Math.Floor(rand * allChars.Length)];
            }
        }
        return generatedPassword;
    }

    public int MinPasswordLength
    {
        get
        {
            return Membership.Provider.MinRequiredPasswordLength;
        }
    }

    public string AdminRole
    {
        get { return "admin"; }
    }

    public string MemberRole
    {
        get { return "member"; }
    }

    public string DelegateRole
    {
        get { return "delegate"; }
    }

    public string AgentRole
    {
        get { return "agent"; }
    }

    public bool Delete(string email)
    {
        return Membership.DeleteUser(email);
    }

    public bool IsAdmin()
    {
        return Roles.IsUserInRole(AdminRole);
    }

    public bool IsMember()
    {
        return Roles.IsUserInRole(MemberRole);
    }

    public bool IsDelegate()
    {
        return Roles.IsUserInRole(DelegateRole);
    }

    public bool IsAgent()
    {
        return Roles.IsUserInRole(AgentRole);
    }

    public bool ChangePassword(string email, string oldPassword, string newPassword)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(email)) throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty.", "email");
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(oldPassword)) throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty.", "oldPassword");
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(newPassword)) throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty.", "newPassword");

        // The underlying ChangePassword() will throw an exception rather
        // than return false in certain failure scenarios.
        try
        {
            var currentUser = Membership.Provider.GetUser(email, true);
            return currentUser.ChangePassword(oldPassword, newPassword);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            return false;
        }
        catch (MembershipPasswordException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public string ResetPassword(string email)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(email)) throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty.", "email");
        Unlock(email);
        var currentUser = Membership.Provider.GetUser(email, false);
        return currentUser.ResetPassword();
    }

    public bool CheckLocked(string email)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(email)) throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty.", "email");
        var currentUser = Membership.Provider.GetUser(email, false);
        if (currentUser == null) return false;
        if (!currentUser.IsLockedOut) return false;
        if (currentUser.LastLockoutDate.AddMinutes(30) < DateTime.Now)
        {
            currentUser.UnlockUser();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public bool Unlock(string email)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(email)) throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty.", "email");
        var currentUser = Membership.Provider.GetUser(email, false);
        if (currentUser == null) return false;
        currentUser.UnlockUser();
        return true;

    }
}
```

I hope it can help!